# Emacs key bindings in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, emacs

I tried to insall "Emacs Emulation" from Extensions and Updates under Visual Studio 2019 preview1 but failed.

Is there a way to make VS 2019 support Emacs key bindings.

Comment: This problem description needs to be expanded to include a *lot* more detail about what you actually tried.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 rc was released.
"Emacs Emulation" still doesn't work.

Comment: I found the following answer useful in the Q&A section of the extension
[Visual Studio Emacs Emulation 2 Q&A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.EmacsEmulation2&ssr=false#qna)
[![description from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.EmacsEmulation2&ssr=false#qna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdTVN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdTVN.png)

Answer (score 2):

According to the following page

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/

One has to do following:

1) Fix version number of InstalltionTarget

```
<Installation InstalledByMsi="false"> 
   <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[14.0,16.0)" /> 
</Installation>
```

2) Fix version number of Prerequisite tag

```
<Prerequisites> 
   <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" /> 
</Prerequisites>
```

For this case,
1) Obtain the code from the following repository:
https://github.com/justcla/EmacsKeys

2) Edit line 25 source.extension.vsixmanifest.

```
"<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,16.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />"
```

Just remove 16.0 and build the extension.
You will get warning but it seems to work.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO, and double thanks for trying to provide a helpful answer! It's generally preferred practice to take the valuable information from the first link you provided and summarize it again here. That will make it easier for others to find the information they need, and ensure that your answer stays relevant even if links break over time.